# I can't get the first modal, in the series of modals, to open

Tags: jquery-plugins

Greeting and thanks for your generosity in providing this wonderful forum,

I'm using `jQuery Orbit Slider and Reveal Modal`. I setup the slider to include content and within the content are hotlinks to a series of modals.

I can't get the first modal, in the series of modals, to open. It appears the plugin is programmatically generating inline CSS that is overriding my CSS stylesheet. Mainly `z-index selector` is keeping the first modal hidden (or invisible). The subsequent modals in that series work as intended.

When viewed using Chrome Inspect Console shows the inconsistency please note at `"featuredContent10"` which is where the `slide4` resides (it's actually a background image). The `data-reveal-id="slide4-1"` is the first one in the series of modals. I did not add the inline styles it's in the `reveal.js` file.

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about reveal and can't find any information regarding a solution. The information I came away with is to ask for assistance on stackoverflow.com. 99.9% of the time I find solution on my own, however, I'm at a lost and my client likes the features of both plugins. Any help you can give me would be very much appreciated.

[If it helps here’s a link to the beta site: http://www.partnershipwithearth.com/thecooperationway-1/](http://www.partnershipwithearth.com/thecooperationway-1/)

Go to Slide 11 lower left link is the culprit. You'll notice the dialog box and close button do appear without the image (slide4-1).

Your expertise is greatly appreciated